# Get all data in loopback HasAndBelongsToMany relationship

Tags: node.js, loopback

**Need all data like below relation, which relation I use.**

[image]

How can I define the relationship?
Thanks.

Comment: set AssemblyPart  "belongsTo" relations to both part and assembly and set Assembly and Part "hasMany" relation to AssemblyPart.

Comment: it'll be good if you upload your model.json code first

Answer (score 0):

On declaration of `many-to-many` relation between two models, one way is to create another table(model) which stores the primary keys of the two related models as a single record. This approach adds an extra fetch from the common (`through`) model to identify the relation between records of the models. But it surely prevents the data redundancy.

In loopback there are two ways of implementing `many-to-many` relationship. If we want an intervening model to be declared explicitly, then `hasMany` relation with a `through` model is used, which is the model that will store the id's of the two related models as a single record. If we don't want any explicit intervening model then we use `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation.

To define the relationship using `hasManyThrough` relation use following format similar to hasMany in both model's definition, but with additional declaration of the `through` model.

in Model1.json:-
`"relations": {
    "relation1": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "modelName2",
      "through": "interveningModelName"
    },`

in Model2.json:-
`"relations": {
    "relation2": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "modelName1",
      "through": "interveningModelName"
    },`

For using `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation through REST api's, we have to declare an intervening model otherwise we cannot use this many-to-many relationship using REST endpoints.
If no declaration of intervening model is done we have to use standard perssistedModel methods (like `create` to add an instance of the relationship between two models).
Furthermore clarification on `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1960